# How to add webhook events to KeyVaults, programmatically?

Tags: azure-sdk-python

I am trying to implement a secret-renewal service for various shared secrets in our environment. My plan for this is to add a webhook event for "Secret expires soon" to each keyvault (there are many), pointing back to a service that knows how to deal with that.

I can do that manually, but I can't figure out which Azure SDK module will allow me to add events to a keyvault. There's no mention of it in the keyvault modules. The eventgrid module wants me to create an eventgrid domain first, and I know I don't need to, because the Portal doesn't do that.

What is managing those event subscriptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an eventsubscription using the eventgrid module *without* needing to create an eventgrid domain first. Here's a simple example:

```py
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.eventgrid import EventGridManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.eventgrid.models import EventSubscriptionFilter, WebHookEventSubscriptionDestination, EventSubscription

    # webhook URL should respond to the eventgrid validation query as usual and have valid HTTPS config
    webhook_url = "https://kv-listener.my-app.com/kv-events"

    subscription_id = "12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890"
    kv_resource_id = "/subscriptions/12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890/resourceGroups/vault-test/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/testvault42"

    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    event_client = EventGridManagementClient(credential, subscription_id=subscription_id)

    subscription_name = "expiry-event-hook"
    destination = WebHookEventSubscriptionDestination(endpoint_url=webhook_url)
    event_filter = EventSubscriptionFilter(
        included_event_types=['Microsoft.KeyVault.SecretNearExpiry', 'Microsoft.KeyVault.SecretExpired']
    )
    the_sub = EventSubscription(
        destination=destination,
        filter=event_filter
    )
    scope = kv_resource_id
    poller = event_client.event_subscriptions.begin_create_or_update(scope, subscription_name, the_sub)
    print("Requested. Waiting on job to finish")
    poller.wait()
    print(f"Finished: {poller.status()}")
```

Answer (score 0):

From Azure Portal, you can go to the Key Vault and use the `events` option.
[key vault events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOjw7.png)

It would allow you to set up triggers for many events for your Vault like:
[Event types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO6ic.png)

Once you select the trigger events, choose an endpoint.  If there's a web hook you want to target, select web hook and enter the address for it:

[endpoint types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aHMm.png)

Note there are 3 different schemas that you can use for the message:
[schema types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhJFU.png)

Comment: And from the SDK? (the question was how to do it _programmatically_)
I've set this up as a proof-of-concept manually as you describe already.

Comment: As the screenshot shows, the implementation is actually done in EventGrid, you have to create your own eventgrid domain (you cannot use the one the Portal is using for themselves) to receive those events. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-key-vault?tabs=event-grid-event-schema

Comment: @LaurentMazuel it turns out that you *don't* have to create an eventgrid domain. I will post an example as an answer.